# Bootstrap 5 How to change the blue color border to a different color from dropdown menu when you click on "Dropdown"

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5. I am trying to change the blue color border to a different color from dropdown menu when you click on "Dropdown" I tried to change it in the css, but it is not overriding the blue border. I would appreciate any suggestions.

[picture of dropdown blue border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekuQS.png)

Here is a link: https://www.codeply.com/p/PI41011ti0

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark d-none d-md-flex" aria-label="navigation bar"> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Here, I'm not see there any border. can you please add screenshot image.

Comment: I added a picture.  If you click on the picture of dropdown blue border link, it will show you the screenshot image.

Comment: please try to use this css `.nav-link:focus {outline: 0;}`

Comment: That removes the blue outline.  Then I can add a white border.  Just to confirm there is no way to swap out the blue color to white?

https://www.codeply.com/p/PI41011ti0

Comment: You can try this `.nav-link:focus {outline-color: #ffffff;}`

Comment: I tried that, but that did not override the blue outline

https://www.codeply.com/p/PI41011ti0

Comment: please try this `.nav-link:focus {
    outline-color: #ffffff;
    outline-style: solid;
}`

Comment: That works. Thank you so much.  I would give a checkmark to indicate it solved my answer, but I don't see one.

https://www.codeply.com/p/PI41011ti0

Comment: I have added answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, It is outline of element when click on. You can hide or change color with below css for that.

**For Change Outline Color:**

```
.nav-link:focus {
    outline-color: #ffffff;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

**For Hide Outline:**

```
.nav-link:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

You can refer for more details here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline-color.asp